# Why wont my segue from UITableView cell to a detailView work?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, xcode4.2, didselectrowatindexpath

Here is my code.....

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"BowlerDetail" sender:self];
}
```

All I get in return is that the cell is still selected, and my detail view does not show up.  Yes, I have checked, and "BowlerDetail" is the name of the segue.  The error message I get is - 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "tc8-Hk-kaK-view-YJA-Me-wti" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: In the pre-xCode 4.2 days, this is how I previously achieved the objective here.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

DetailView *detailVC = [[DetailView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailVC animated:YES];


[detailVC release];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you used a push segue and you didn't  use a UINavigationController as a root view controller.So add a UINavigationController as a root view Controller or change the segue to modal.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to perform a segue programatically, you can connect your cell's prototype in IB by option-clicking the cell and dragging the "Modal" segue to the view you want to present.

And with your code? Is this method inside the view that is visible when starting a segue? Are both views in storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

`[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];`. You calling this method from itself. is that you whant? i think you should remove this.

Comment: I removed that line, and came up with the same error.  I added the code that used to work to my question, I am having trouble translating it to xCode 4.2.

Comment: you initing view controller without xib file: `initWithNibName:nil` is thst what you whant? You implementing you gratpics 100%-programmatically?!

Comment: That was my previous solution when I was using nib files, instead of a storyboard.

Comment: well, your error sais, that it can't find tableView from whatever you trying to load it. You shoul chack out if there is oll OK with it.